# Calling custom function in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 2 different Custom functions defined. First function takes one argument, and second function takes two arguments. But they way of calling function is different, why i can't call second function like the way the first function being called? Below are my two functions, and how i am calling them.

```
Function with single argument:-

def convert_sqft_to_num(x):
    tokens = x.split('-')
    if len(tokens) == 2:
        return (float(tokens[0])+float(tokens[1]))/2
    try:
        return float(x)
    except:
        return None
        
df1.total_sqft = df1.total_sqft.apply(convert_sqft_to_num)

Second function with multiple arguments:-

def corr_sft_outlier(in_bhk, in_sft):
    bhk_band = np.quantile(outlierdf2[outlierdf2.bhk_size==in_bhk]['avg_sft'], (.20,.90))
    lower_band = round(bhk_band[0])
    upper_band = round(bhk_band[1])
    if (in_sft>=lower_band)&(in_sft<=upper_band):
        return in_sft
    elif (in_sft<lower_band):
        return lower_band
    elif (in_sft>upper_band):
        return upper_band
    else:
        return None
```

Below is the second function call

```
outlierdf2['adj_avg_sft'] = outlierdf2.apply(lambda x: corr_sft_outlier(x['bhk_size'],x['avg_sft']), axis=1)
```

I want to call above function as below

```
outlierdf2['adj_avg_sft'] = outlierdf2[['bhk_size','avg_sft']].apply(corr_sft_outlier)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. This does not work?:
outlierdf2['adj_avg_sft'] = outlierdf2.apply(lambda x: corr_sft_outlier(x['bhk_size'],x['avg_sft']), axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a function that has 2 arguments with 1 parameters, in this part :

```
outlierdf2[['bhk_size','avg_sft']].apply(corr_sft_outlier)
```

you are passing a "df row with 2 columns" not 2 values. So whether you make a frame of two columns (i.e. outlierdf2[["bhk_size","avg_sft"]].apply) or call it with the df itself (i.e. outlierdf2.apply) you have to pass the proper number of parameters. So you can change you function like this then call it the way you want:

```
def corr_sft_outlier(row):
    in_bhk, in_sft = row['bhk_size'],row['avg_sft']
    bhk_band = np.quantile(outlierdf2[outlierdf2.bhk_size==in_bhk]['avg_sft'], (.20,.90))
    lower_band = round(bhk_band[0])
    upper_band = round(bhk_band[1])
    if (in_sft>=lower_band)&(in_sft<=upper_band):
        return in_sft
    elif (in_sft<lower_band):
        return lower_band
    elif (in_sft>upper_band):
        return upper_band
    else:
        return None

outlierdf2['adj_avg_sft'] = outlierdf2[['bhk_size','avg_sft']].apply(corr_sft_outlier,axis=1)
```